# LINQ Where statement in collection

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a Customer object which has a collection of ContactNumbers.
Is it possible with LINQ to get a list of Customers where one of the contact numbers = '123'?

```
Public Class Customer
    Public Overridable Property ContactNumbers As List(Of ContactNumber)

End Class

Public Class ContactNumber

    <Required()>
    Public Property ID As Integer

    <Required()>
    <StringLength(20)>
    Public Property Number As String

    Public Overridable Property Type As ContactNumberType

    Public Property Primary As Boolean

End Class


Dim findnumber as String = '123'
Dim customers = db.customers.tolist

customers = customers.Where..... ?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following

```
customers = customers.Where(Function (x) x.ContactNumbers.Any(Function (y) y.Number = "123"))
```

The trick here is the `Any` function.  This will return `True` if any of the items in the collection match the predicate.  In this case `y.Number = 123`